# Compiles only lib, but no dll

Tags: visual-c++

Trying to build winsparkle library. Library compiles and lib file is created, but there is no dll file. Why? `Configuration properties -> General->Configuration type` is set to `Dynamic Library (.dll)`

Answer (score 0):

You could download them here https://github.com/vslavik/winsparkle/releases/tag/v0.4

I have build it. Could u try to do it on different pc?